# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

tengo un problema con el siguiente código donde la respuesta es esta:
[image: Respuesta JSONP]

Como se puede ver hay respuesta pero me sale ese error y no me carga. Gracias adelantadas!

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var mb = document.getElementById("myBtn");
 mb.addEventListener("click", jsonparser1);
}

function jsonparser1() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/kappaequiscu1v9?api_key=RGAPI-9536b7c8-f23f-40a9-aea5-7a5bcd879205",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        success: function (xhr) {
   
   var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   document.getElementById("span").innerText = response.accountId;
  }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>DSFSF</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>API KAPPAEQUISCU</h2>
<h3>Search:</h3>

<!--<input type="text" id="summoner">-->
<input type="submit" id="myBtn">

<h3>Response:</h3>

<span id="span"></span>
<span id="spanDos"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: preuba con dataType: "JSON",

Comment: Con JSON hay problema con CORS, lo he probado antes @EdwinCubillos

Comment: Ya se por que es.

Comment: Has podido solucionarlo? me encuentro con el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Hola tienes un error en la `ulr`

pero también debes ver que la función se está ejecutando apenas se carga el `html`.

lo correcto sería

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mb = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    mb.addEventListener("click", jsonparser1);
}

function jsonparser1() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/kappaequiscu1v9?api_key=RGAPI-9536b7c8-f23f-40a9-aea5-7a5bcd879205/",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        success: function (xhr) {

            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("span").innerText = response.accountId;
        }
    });
}
```

El error es que tienes que completar la url con `/`;

Saludos.

Comment: Sigue dando error aunque uno diferente ahora (https://gyazo.com/08ead6f85645fe15ebd3b767ce5cf536)